# import JSON file with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I want data from the config.json file import to the index.js file in the same dir.

so I had it before

```
const {
prefix, token
} = require('./config.json');
```

now i would change the string so i need a json object, but how?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. > In ES5 you can do it by

```js
const object = require('./config.json');
```

The object will contain your JSON.

In ES6

```
import object from './config.json'
```

2. > Using fs module synchronously

```js
const fs = require('fs')
const jsonData = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('config.json', 'utf-8'))
```

Comment: Note: to import as json in ES6 `"resolveJsonModule": true,` must be set under `compilerOptions` in your `tsconfig.json` file.

Answer (score 1):

Async example, if you're using ES6 modules:

```
import fs from 'fs/promises';

const {prefix, token} = JSON.parse(
  await fs.readFile('./config.json', 'utf-8')
);
```

See also:

- https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#promises-api
- https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#determining-module-system

Answer (score -1):

If you want the whole object, simply use:

```js
const config = require('./config.json');
```

Otherwise if you want the contents of `config.json`, you can simply use the [`fs`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) module to read the file. More specifically [`fs.readFileSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options) if you want it to be synchronous.